# Extracting coefficients from logistic regression with for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, glm, logistic-regression, coefficients

I have a logistic regression to estimate nest success, you will find some data in this link:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/okp2iudnace6fha/data1.csv?dl=0

All my explanatory variables are continuous to get a linear trend. I want to analyze if there is a change over time on the seasonal variation of nest survival:

yr (as 0,1,2,3...)

laying date (LD)

NestAge

This is my model:

```
glm(survive~LD+yr+yr^2+LD:yr+LD:yr^2+NestAge,family=binomial(link=logexp(data1$exposure)), data=data1)
```

This is the link exposure I am using:

```
 library(MASS)
    logexp <- function(exposure = 1)
    {
      linkfun <- function(mu) qlogis(mu^(1/exposure))
      ## FIXME: is there some trick we can play here to allow
      ##   evaluation in the context of the 'data' argument?
      linkinv <- function(eta)  plogis(eta)^exposure
      mu.eta <- function(eta) exposure * plogis(eta)^(exposure-1) *
        .Call(stats:::C_logit_mu_eta, eta, PACKAGE = "stats")
      valideta <- function(eta) TRUE
      link <- paste("logexp(", deparse(substitute(exposure)), ")",
                    sep="")
      structure(list(linkfun = linkfun, linkinv = linkinv,
                     mu.eta = mu.eta, valideta = valideta, 
                     name = link),
                class = "link-glm")
    }
```

To get the coefficients I created a loop that extracts the but it is not working.

```
a<-as.matrix(coef(model))
intercept<-a[1,]
slope<-a[2,]
for (i in 1:6) { 
  i<-as.numeric(i)
  sub<-subset(data1,data1$yr==i )
  g<- intercept + slope*sub$yr[i]
  dsr <-exp(g)/ (1+ exp(g))
}
```

Can you please help me to fix it? Thank you in advance.

Comment: what is the yra referring to in the line: `sub<-subset(data1,data1$yra==i )`? It's not one of the variables on data1.

Comment: Also why are you looping i 26 times when none of the variables in the data set consists of 26 levels of factor. Checked with `sapply(names(data1), function(x)table(data1[,x]) %>% length)` which gives levels for year,  nest, yr, exposure,  survive,  fate, LD and  NestAge as length of 6, 699, 6, 30,  2,  2, 33, 33.

Comment: It's true! I'm sorry and thank you for telling me, I already edited my code. It was 26 because it is the complete dataset (I want to keep the data example in my dropbox).

Answer (score 0):

It works now:

```
dsr=0
for (i in 1:6) { 
  i<-as.numeric(i)
  sub<-subset(data1,data1$yr==i )
  g<- intercept + slope*sub$yr[i]
  dsr [i]<-plogis(g)
}
```